# RichFaces FileUpload without Add Button and call by commandLink

Tags: jquery, file-upload, jsf-2, xhtml, richfaces

I am using Richfaces 4 fileupload to upload one file.

But in my case i just want to click in one link and see the browser to select the file.

So in my code i have commandLink:

```
<a4j:commandLink id="showFileUpload"
                    execute="@this"
                action="#{doSomething.Something(a)}"
                render="@none" 
                oncomplete="#{rich:element('stratFileUpload')}.click();"
                >
                <h:graphicImage value="/images/A.png" />
            </a4j:commandLink>
```

And the part of the fileUpload is just a form with the fileUpload on it:

```
<h:form id="stratFileUploadForm">
    <rich:fileUpload id="stratFileUpload" execute="@this"
        fileUploadListener="#{doUploadedFile}"
        onuploadcomplete="
                                    jQuery(#{rich:element('stratFileUpload')}).find('.rf-fu-itm-lnk').click();
                                    "
        noDuplicate="true" maxFilesQuantity="1"
        sizeExceededLabel="#{msg['sizeExceeded']}"
        uploadLabel="#{msg['upload']}" />
</h:form>
```

I already call in the commandLink the id form and rich:fileUpload id but nothing works.

The only way for this to work is with popup, and in that case it came with the "+ Add" button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because of the the upload browser as been block by the Chrome, in the Chrome i can't access the browser to choose the files, but in the IE, Edge and Firefox i can see that browser. Chrome block the browser files (popup), because of the time between the action and the oncomplete

This part of the code:

```
 <a4j:commandLink id="showFileUpload"
                     execute="@this"
                 action="#{doSomething.Something(a)}"
     ...
             </a4j:commandLink>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it's RichFaces 2.0?

Clicking on the fileUpload does nothing (just like if you click manually). You have to click on the file input, e.g.

```
$(".rf-fu-btn-cnt-add input").click()
```

but I'm not sure if all browsers let you do that when the button is hidden.

Comment: So change the oncomplete to this (oncomplete="#{rich:element('.rf-fu-btn-cnt-add input')}.click();")

Comment: the Richfaces is the 4 version sry

Comment: Keep it as it is (or change $ to jQuery if you have to), you're not looking up ids.

Comment: I already try everything, the google Chrome blocks my pop up, In Mozilla Firefox and IE is working fine... This happens because the click is not made by the user. "oncomplete" waits for the "action"  and because of that exists a delay that makes chrome to block the pop up.